# What is the process when a new tag contains a spelling mistake?

Tags: support, tags

I recently approved a suggested edit to correct a new tag that was created with a spelling mistake: [What are the moving glowing balls in slither.io?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262290/what-are-the-moving-glowing-balls-in-slither-io)

Assuming the edit is accepted, and the question is then tagged correctly, what happens to the old "orphan" tag?  Does this need manual deletion / mod intervention or is a system in place to remove the tag?  In other words, do I need to do anything else beyond accepting the suggested edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags with no questions are automatically deleted after some time. I think it's 30 days, but I would have to look it up.

Either way, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I think it's a bit quicker than 30 days, I thought it was closer to 24 hours at most it seems the script is run once a day.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely closer to 24 hours.